# Sometime will hit error of MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 127.0.0.1:27017 closed

Tags: mongodb, graphql, connection

i am using mongodb native driver to serve my nextjs and graphql web. it's work. But sometime it will show this error **MongoServerSelectionError: connection  to 127.0.0.1:27017 closed**, cause it cannot run in my local environment.

i wondering what issue causing this happen?

below command that checked the mongodb connection from my terminal, it show 1 connection. yeah, it is connected in my local. why it will hit **MongoServerSelectionError** ???

```sh
ps -ef | grep mongod | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -d ' '
```

i need to restart mongodb connection or re-serve my web again (yarn dev).

**Updated:**
In local.env file, i store the MONGDO_URL

```
//local.env
MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/fruits

 // graphql.js
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: async ({ res, req }) => {
    if (!db) {
      try {
        const dbClient = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });

        if (!dbClient.isConnected()) await dbClient.connect();
        db = dbClient.db("fruits");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(
          `error while connecting with graphql context (db): `,
          error
        );
      }
    }
    return { db, res, req };
  },
});
```

Comment: You have a client object that connects to the default address?

Comment: yes. i updated the question agian. please take a loook.

Comment: no answer :((((